# Necesito listar un arrayList en java , pero solo me lista el primer elemento de mi arreglo

Tags: java, base-de-datos, jsp, servlets

Necesito listar un arreglo para mostrarlo en una tabla (específicamente la tabla usuario con sus atributos) , estoy usando JSTL para mostrar los datos en el JSP , el unico problema es que solo me lista el primer objeto de mi ArrayList  , aca les dejo el codigo de la función que genera el ArrayList.

```
public List<Usuario_DTO_bean> listarUsuarios() {
    List<Usuario_DTO_bean> listaUsuario= new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        con=Conector.connect();
        String sql = "select * from usuario";
        Statement statement=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String usu = resultSet.getString("usuario");
            String clave = resultSet.getString("clave");
            String permisos=resultSet.getString("permisos");
            int estado=resultSet.getInt("estado");

            Usuario_DTO_bean usuario_DTO_bean=new Usuario_DTO_bean(id, usu, clave, permisos, estado);
            listaUsuario.add(usuario_DTO_bean); 
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            con.close();
            System.out.println("nuevo registro");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return listaUsuario;
}
```

Cuando llamo a imprimir el primer dato por consola no hay problema, el siguiente es el codigo que esta en una clase main que uso para mostrar datos por consola

```
Usuario_DTO_bo listar=new Usuario_DTO_bo();
    List<Usuario_DTO_bean> lista=new ArrayList<>();
    lista=listar.listarUsuarios();
    int tamano=lista.size();
    String aux=lista.get(0).getUsuario();
    System.out.println(aux);
    System.out.println(tamano);
```

Resultado por consola

[image]

Cuando accedo al la posicion 1 o superior de mi arreglo para leer los datos me manda el sgte error (que es porque el arrayList solo tiene 1 elemento lo se)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías cerrar el `reader` fuera del `while`, así no tiene sentido

```
public List<Usuario_DTO_bean> listarUsuarios() {
    List<Usuario_DTO_bean> listaUsuario= new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        con=Conector.connect();
        String sql = "select * from usuario";
        Statement statement=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String usu = resultSet.getString("usuario");
            String clave = resultSet.getString("clave");
            String permisos=resultSet.getString("permisos");
            int estado=resultSet.getInt("estado");

            Usuario_DTO_bean usuario_DTO_bean=new Usuario_DTO_bean(id, usu, clave, permisos, estado);
            listaUsuario.add(usuario_DTO_bean); 

            System.out.println("nuevo registro");
        }
             resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return listaUsuario;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa es la solución :D  !  Vaya error, yo mismo me cerraba la conexión a la base de datos

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Usuario_DTO_bean> listarUsuarios() {
List<Usuario_DTO_bean> listaUsuario= new ArrayList<>();
try {
    con = Conector.connect();
    String sql = "select * from usuario";
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    while(resultSet.next()) {            
        int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
        String usu = resultSet.getString("usuario");
        String clave = resultSet.getString("clave");
        String permisos=resultSet.getString("permisos");
        int estado=resultSet.getInt("estado");

        Usuario_DTO_bean usuario_DTO_bean=new Usuario_DTO_bean(id, usu, clave, permisos, estado);
        listaUsuario.add(usuario_DTO_bean); 

        System.out.println("nuevo registro");
    }
        /*Se cierra siempre al ultimo*/
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        con.close();
        /*Deberias de importar la excepcion SQLException*/
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}finally{
/*Es una buena practica agregar el finally, por lo general aquí se cierra
La conexion a la BD algo como Conector.desconectar()*/
}
return listaUsuario;}
```

En el main lo trabajaria de la siguiente manera, intuyendo que en Usuario_DTO_bean estan los metodos accesores, los getters y setters.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
       Usuario_DTO_bo user = new Usuario_DTO_bo();
       List<Usuario_DTO_bean> listaUsuarios = user.listarUsuarios();
       for(Usuario_DTO_bean usuario: listaUsuarios){
//Imprimes cada atributo del usuario, por poner un ejemplo:
          System.out.println("Usuario: " +usuario.getNombre());
       }
```

Comment: Bueno mi error fue poner las funciones de cierre al dentro del try como señalo un usuario anterior, por otro lado agradezco la correcion en el main, usare tu metodo for :D , por ultimo cual es el problema que mi metodo de  cierre de conexion (con.close ) no este en el finally ?

Comment: No, no es ningún error, como te dije solo es una buena práctica. Sucede que haya o no haya una excepción la sección finally siempre se va a ejecutar, es por ello que en esa sección se suele hacer el cierre de las conexiones.

Answer (score 0):

podrías crear un for-each para poder visualizar el contenido de tu arrayList y más aún si es de Object, hay que hacerlo si o si